# SwiftUI transition offset

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a circle which has an offset. The circle appears with a scale animation when I press a button. The problem is that the animation does not start at the offset position of the circle, it starts at it's original position. How do i get the animation to start at the offset position of the circle.

```
Circle()
    .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
    .foregroundColor(.red)
    .transition(.scale)
    .offset(x: -69, y: 0)
```

Comment: Try putting the scale modifier after the offset modifier in the list of modifiers.

Comment: I don't think the answer or the comment are getting to the heart of your question.  Weren't you wanting the red circle to start growing from its offset position, and not from the origin?

Comment: I want the circle to start growing from its offset position.

Answer (score 2):

Just add animation to transition, like below (tested with Xcode 11.4)

[image: demo]

```
struct Test: View {
    @State private var show = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Tap") {
                withAnimation {
                    self.show.toggle()
                }
            }
            if show {
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.scale.animation(.default)) // here !!
                    .offset(x: -69, y: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. In this example the animation starts in the middle of the screen, but I am looking for a way to start the animation right there were it ends.

Comment: The `.offset` modifier does not change position of view (add .border to your circle and you'll see), so any position-dependent transitions (`slide`, `scale`, `move`) will take into account *real* location of view, but not *visual*. But *visual* transitions, like `.opacity`, will take places on *visual* locations. The demo above just shows how to animate transitions at all in correct way, so if you expect other effect, just change layout to have *real* position of view where you want it to be and transition animate it as should, because it is not a transition problem.

Comment: This does not solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Use alignment guides:

```
struct ViewsExercise: View {
    @State var show = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            Spacer()
            Button("Tap") {
                self.show.toggle()
            }
            .font(.title)

            if show {
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { d in
                        64
                    })
                    .transition(AnyTransition.scale.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)))
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

You can learn more about alignment guides [here](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/). As @Asperi mentioned, the .offset modifier does not change position of view. The view is still at (0,0), so the transition happens at the origin point. If you want to "physically" offset the view then you should use alignment guides.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A lot is to do with the order in which the modifiers are called. You could try something like this:

```
enum ScaleFactor: Double {
        case full = 1.0
        case zero = 0.0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            Spacer()
            Button("Tap") {
                scaleFactor = scaleFactor == .zero ? .full : .zero
            }
            .font(.title)
            
            Circle()
                .scaleEffect(scaleFactor.rawValue)
                .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .offset(x: -150, y: 0)
                .animation(.linear(duration: 1), value: scaleFactor)
        }
    }
```

This will toggle between 0.0 and 1.0 scale factor and because the scaleEffect is before the offset, you will find that it scales in situ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of awkward things are happening here:

1. `.transition(.scale)` is interpolating for whatever notion SwiftUI internally has for `.offset()` from `.zero` to your final position; normally, it refuses to make such interpolations which should've resulted in no animation instead of animating from screen center (this is probably a bug, though I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for a fix because apps probably rely on this by now)
2. if your view is conditional, `.transition()` seems to ignore modifier application order, instead operating on the entire "no view -> some view" transition, though this might be a consequence of the default set in #1
3. using `.animation(:value:)` results in the same situation if the view is conditional, regardless of whether `value` is the same as the display condition

The workaround I've found is to use `.animation(:value:)` with an explicit `.scaleEffect()` bound to a `@State` var that is updated on the next tick using `.onAppear` and `.onDisappear`, e.g.

```swift
var displayAtOffset: CGPoint?
@State var visible = false

var body: some View {
    if let position = displayAtOffset {
        DefinitelyNotARadialMenu()
            .scaleEffect(visible ? 1 : 0)
            .animation(.interactiveSpring(), value: visible) // value != (displayAtOffset != nil)
            .position(position) // .offset() should also work if you account for size
            .onAppear { visible = true }
    }
}
```

If you want your view to also *scale out* instead of pop out of existence, you'll want to delay updating the initial condition (e.g. `displayAtOffset`) until you're confident that the animation you triggered by setting `visible = false` is complete.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been said, Offset do not change view position.

But you can compensate the offset by using an anchor point for your translation (rotation, scale, etc).

What is tricky is to compute the anchor point properly. Here is an example that compensate the Offset and make the scale translation occurs relative to the center of the object:

```
struct TestOffsetScaleView : View {

@State var show = false

let objectSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 100)
let offset = CGSize(width: 50, height: 125)

private func anchorPoint() -> UnitPoint {
    let anchorX = (offset.width + objectSize.width/2.0) / objectSize.width
    let anchorY = (offset.height + objectSize.height/2.0) / objectSize.height
    return UnitPoint(x: anchorX, y: anchorY)
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        
        if show {
            
            
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: objectSize.width, height: objectSize.height)
                .offset(offset)
                .transition(.scale(scale: 0.0, anchor: anchorPoint()))
        }
        
        Button("Show") {
            withAnimation {
                show.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}